# Spring Mongotemplate fails when creating the instance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using the MongoTemplate for fetching the Data from MongoDb.Below is the code of my POJO and the method getting the data from Mongo.I am getting the exception upon the API hit.This is a PATCH API call.
This is a Spring application and not a Spring boot application
POJO

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Document(collection = "my_mongo_collection")
public class MyClass extends ParentClass implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1490956384479197360L;

    @JsonProperty("identityNumber")
    private Long identityNumber;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    private Long title;

    @JsonProperty("reviews")
    private Review reviews;

    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }

    @JsonProperty("identityNumber")
    public Long getIdentityNumber() {
        return identityNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty("identityNumber")
    public void setIdentityNumber(Long identityNumber) {
        this.identityNumber = identityNumber;
    }

    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    @JsonProperty("title")
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @JsonProperty("reviews")
    public Review getReviews() {
        return reviews;
    }

    @JsonProperty("reviews")
    public void setReviews(Review reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new ToStringBuilder(this).append("Subscription [id=").append(super.getId())
                .append(", name=", super.getName()).append(" , identity=", identity).append(",reviews=", reviews)
                .append("} ]").toString();

    }
}
```

Method accessing the data from Mongo :

```
private List<MyClass> getAllValues(Long identity, String title) {
         Query query= new Query();
        memSubscriptionQuery.addCriteria(Criteria.where("identityNumber").is(identityNumber).and("title").is(title));
        return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass .class);


    }
```

The below Exception is being thrown:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate java.util.List using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64)

at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:258)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:877)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:278)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:194)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:2313)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1966)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1784)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1767)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:632)
    at
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoTemplate.find() return a List which OP used is correct. As the exception notice, OP should create another Constructor to include all variables (like @AllArgConstructors).

Answer (score -1):

Looks Like you are passing a `Class` object to mongo template and expecting a `List` in return.

```
return mongoTemplate.find(query, MyClass .class);
```

You probably have to change the return type of the method to `MyClass`.

```
private MyClass getAllValues(Long identity, String title)
```

If you need a list and not a object you have to wrap you class object in another class that gets the list of object.

Comment: what is the wrapping option?.Can you please provide the glimpse of  the code snapshot of that if I can return the list of MyClass objects.

Comment: Can you also provide the json you are trying to parse ?

Comment: @M.WaqasPervez I dont think that is an answer. MongoTemplate.find() return a List<T> which OP used is correct. As the exception notice, OP should create another Constructor to include all variables (like @AllArgConstructors).